# Is it known for which sequential integer the MD5 algorithm produces the first non-unique hash?

Tags: hash, md5

Question edited because my example attracted the wrong kind of anwsers.

So being very specific here, if I take a sequence of integers, starting from 1, and increasing into infinity, and do an MD5 hash of each of them, which will be the first number that will produce a hash that has already been produced by another number?

For example if the MD5 hash for the number 8.501.668 happens to be the same as the MD5 hash for the number 12, then that number 8.501.668 is the first (lowest) number when this collision happens.

My question is therefore, do we actually know specifically at which number this will happen, when using MD5?

I see a lot of people trying to calculate the odds of a collision happening. But odds are not specific, having in mind that starting with the number 1 and working your way up, there is a definite way to know which number will be the first one to produce a repeating hash. Only, I am unable to calculate this number myself, due to processor power etc. And I haven't managed to find anyone already answer this question in a specific manner.

Comment: If your thing is based on simple incrementing id's you probably do not have to worry about this.

Comment: Also if your thing is based on hashes of id's it is useless

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem -- you'll get more useful responses if you asked a question about your underlying goals rather than asking for information about your idea for achieving those goals.

Comment: MD5s are also easy to "guess" (one can simply compute them) and for small numbers they can even be simply "reverted" with rainbow tables. Simply using hashes of ID's instead of ID's doesn't make much of a difference. Why do you need these values to be difficult to guess?

Comment: @Hurkyl My goal is just to have a guarantee that the generated URL's will be unique, it's all in the question and that is as complicated as it gets, nothing more to it. But my goal is also irrelevant, because the actual question, for which the purpose shouldn't be mandatory, is for which lowest number does MD5 generate the first non-unique hash.

Comment: @SukcesElektroniki I don't need you to solve a programming problem, or "change an approach" in an algorithm, that example was just an example, and is now edited out of the question since it confused multiple people. So, I only want to know which is the first number that produces the first non-unique value, that is all.

Comment: @ImNotMike: In the majority of XY situations, the asker only really cares about getting an answer for X: it would have been negligent to ignore the possibility that this is one of them. Since you've clarified, the point of the comment has been achieved, even if not in the way I had expected!

Comment: Just asked the same question in crypto site, seems that this is unknown yet: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64428/what-is-the-smallest-last-value-of-sequence-of-integers-from-1-where-there-is-a